# Why do I get an error about strings in my deciphering program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am trying to make some sort of decipherer. The program asks you to enter a phrase and it will decrypt it. For example, if I enter "hi", it should show as "ef". However, all I get is an error, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

I'm not sure what to do, I've tried fiddling around with the code with no good results.

````py
def plainText(string):
    cipher = ''
    for i in string:
        if i == ' ':
            cipher = cipher - i
        elif i.isupper():
            cipher = cipher + chr((ord(i) - 3 - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            cipher = cipher + chr((ord(i) - 3 - 97) % 26 + 97)
    return cipher
message = input("What's your message?")
print("Your decrypted message is: ", plainText(message))
print("Your original message was: ", message)```

Again, the error was

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' at line 7. 

Thank you in advance!
````

Comment: What does string subtraction look like? It's not a supported use of the subtraction operator. What is it you're trying to accomplish with `cipher = cipher - i` when both are strings?

Comment: Nevermind, thanks for the help. I realized that instead of cipher = cipher - i it should be cipher = cipher + i.